# It doesn't reach the end of file when reading

Tags: c++, file

I have created a function to analyze a text in a file according to some rules.

```
void parse(const char *fileName){
    ifstream f;
    f.open("test.txt");
    char ch;
    string str = "";
    while(!f.eof()){
        f.get(ch);
        if(isspace(ch)){
            cout << ch << " -> Space." << endl;
        } else if(ch == '/'){
            cout << ch << " -> Symble." << endl;
        } else if(isalpha(ch)){
            str = ch;
            f.get(ch);
            while(isalnum(ch)){
                str += ch;
                f.get(ch);
            }
            f.putback(ch);
            cout << str << " -> String." << endl;
        } else if(isdigit(ch)){
            str = ch;
            f.get(ch);
            while(isdigit(ch)){
                str += ch;
                f.get(ch);
            }
            f.putback(ch);
            cout << str << " -> Number." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << ch << " -> Wrong value." << endl;
        }
    }
    f.close();
}

// The implementation
int main(){
    parse("test.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

The content of `test.txt` for example:

> Lion King 200 26/12/1910

After searching for the problem I found when reaching the last character it is repeated continuously and does not reach the end of the file.

**Debugging window:**

[image]

**The result:**

[image]

**How to make the function to reach the end of file?**

---

## **(+) A way to solve the problem but not the best.**

I have solved the problem but using a bad way in my opinion, I've put a condition in several places to know if I have reached the end of file. `if(f.eof()) break;`

```
void parse(const char *fileName){
    ifstream f;
    f.open("test.txt");
    char ch;
    string str = "";
    while(!f.eof()){
        f.get(ch);
        if(isspace(ch)){
            if(f.eof()) break;
            cout << ch << " -> Space." << endl;
        } else if(ch == '/'){
            if(f.eof()) break;
            cout << ch << " -> Symble." << endl;
        } else if(isalpha(ch)){
            str = ch;
            f.get(ch);
            while(isalnum(ch)){
                str += ch;
                f.get(ch);
                if(f.eof()) break;
            }
            cout << str << " -> String." << endl;
            if(f.eof()) break;
            f.putback(ch);
        } else if(isdigit(ch)){
            str = ch;
            f.get(ch);
            while(isdigit(ch)){
                str += ch;
                f.get(ch);
                if(f.eof()) break;
            }
            cout << str << " -> Number." << endl;
            if(f.eof()) break;
            f.putback(ch);
        } else {
            if(f.eof()) break;
            cout << ch << " -> Wrong value." << endl;
        }
    }
    f.close();
}
```

Is there another good way instead that?

Comment: Better read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach to dealing with reading input from a stream needs to be rethought. Any time you read from a stream, you have to verify that the read was successful before you proceed to use the value that was read from the stream.

It's better to use `if (f)` / `while (f)` instead of `if (f.eof())` / `while (f.eof())`.

Here's an updated version of your function that should work.

```
void parse(const char *fileName){
   ifstream f;
   f.open("test.txt");
   char ch;
   string str = "";

   // If a char can't be read, don't enter the loop.
   while(f.get(ch))
   {
      if(isspace(ch)){
         cout << ch << " -> Space." << endl;
      } else if(ch == '/'){
         cout << ch << " -> Symble." << endl;
      } else if(isalpha(ch)){
         str = ch;

         // Read the character and proceed to isalnum only
         // if read was successful.
         while(f.get(ch) && isalnum(ch)){
            str += ch;
         }
         cout << str << " -> String." << endl;

         // Don't call putback unless the stream is still in a no error state.
         if ( f ) {
            f.putback(ch);
         }
      } else if(isdigit(ch)){
         str = ch;
         // Read the character and proceed to isdigit only
         // if read was successful.
         while(f.get(ch) && isdigit(ch)){
            str += ch;
         }
         cout << str << " -> Number." << endl;

         // Don't call putback unless the stream is still in a no error state.
         if ( f ) {
            f.putback(ch);
         }
      } else {
         if(!f) break;
         cout << ch << " -> Wrong value." << endl;
      }
   }
   f.close();
}
```

---

A few suggestions to make the function simpler.

**Suggestion 1**

Combine

```
ifstream f;
f.open("test.txt");
```

to one line

```
ifstream f("test.txt");
```

**Suggestion 2**

You are passing `fileName` as argument but have hard coded file name `test.txt` in the function. I think it will be better to use `fileName`.

```
ifstream f(fileName);
```

**Suggestion 3**

There is no harm in the line

```
f.close();
```

but it is unnecessary. The file will be closed when the function returns.

**Suggestion 4**

You can process the contents of the file by reading lines of text and processing the lines instead of having function calls to read one character at a time in multiple places. It will also allow you to make the function simpler. You can create smaller functions to make the code simpler.

```
std::string::iterator parseAlphaNumeric(std::string::iterator start,
                                        std::string::iterator end)
{
   // Iterate over the string until we reach the end of the
   // line or the first character that is not an alphanumeric character.
   std::string::iterator iter = start;
   for ( ++iter; iter != end && isalnum(*iter); ++iter );

   // Create a string using the itertors instead of
   // adding to the string one character at a time.
   std::cout << std::string(start, iter) << " -> String." << std::endl;

   // The iterator now points to either the end of the line
   // or the first character that is not an alphanumeric character.
   return iter;
}

std::string::iterator parseNumeric(std::string::iterator start,
                                   std::string::iterator end)
{
   // See comments in the previous function.

   std::string::iterator iter = start;
   for ( ++iter; iter != end && isdigit(*iter); ++iter );
   std::cout << std::string(start, iter) << " -> Number." << std::endl;
   return iter;
}

void parseLine(std::string::iterator iter,
               std::string::iterator end)
{
   while ( iter != end )
   {
      char ch = *iter;
      if(isspace(ch)){
         std::cout << ch << " -> Space." << std::endl;
         ++iter;
      } else if(ch == '/'){
         std::cout << ch << " -> Symble." << std::endl;
         ++iter;
      } else if(isalpha(ch)){
         iter = parseAlphaNumeric(iter, end);
      } else if(isdigit(ch)){
         iter = parseNumeric(iter, end);
      } else {
         std::cout << ch << " -> Wrong value." << std::endl;
         ++iter;
      }
   }
}

void parse(const char *fileName){
   std::ifstream f(fileName);

   // Read lines of text and process each line.
   std::string line;
   while(getline(f, line))
   {
      parseLine(line.begin(), line.end());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When it reaches EOF (or any kind of failure), `f.get(ch)` does not change `ch`.

```
        while(isdigit(ch)){
            str += ch;
            f.get(ch);
        }
```

So you're simply stuck at this loop and keeps on appending the last available `ch` to `str`.

Make sure you're actually checking EOF instead of relying on `isdigit(ch)`:

```
        while(isdigit(ch)){
            str += ch;
            if (!f.get(ch)) break;
        }
```

From [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get):

> ```
> basic_istream& get( char_type& ch );
> ```
>
> Reads one character and stores it to `ch` **if available. Otherwise, leaves `ch` unmodified** and sets `failbit` and `eofbit`. Note that this function is not overloaded on the types `signed char` and `unsigned char`, unlike the formatted character input `operator>>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, when changing to `if (!f.get(ch)) break;` infinity loop occurs.

Comment: @LionKing Drop that `f.putback` when an error occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely stream never ends since you put symbols back:

```
f.get(ch);
// ...
f.putback(ch);
```

Also note that you should check stream status after every `get` call, not just once per loop iteration.